# Must the Spark Streaming developer install Hadoop on his computer?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to learn spark streaming, when my demo set Master is "local[2]", it is normal. But when I setMaster for the local cluster started in StandAlone mode, an error occurred:
lost an executor 2 (already removed): Unable to create executor due to java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: HADOOP_HOME and hadoop.home.dir are unset.

It should be noted that I submitted the code in idea

```
@Component
public final class JavaNetworkWordCount {

    private static final String SPACE = " ";

    @Bean("test")
    public void test() throws Exception {

        // Create a local StreamingContext with two working thread and batch interval of 10 second
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .setJars(new String[]{"E:\\project\\spark-demo\\target\\spark-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"})
                .setMaster("spark://10.4.41.93:7077")
                .set("spark.driver.host", "127.0.0.1")
                .setAppName("JavaWordCount");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf, Durations.seconds(1));


        // Create a DStream that will connect to hostname:port, like localhost:9999
        JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = jssc.socketTextStream("192.168.2.51", 9999);

        // Split each line into words
        JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(SPACE)).iterator());

        // Count each word in each batch
        JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> pairs = words.mapToPair(s -> new Tuple2<>(s, 1));
        JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey((i1, i2) -> i1 + i2);

        // Print the first ten elements of each RDD generated in this DStream to the console
        wordCounts.print();

        jssc.start();              // Start the computation
        jssc.awaitTermination();   // Wait for the computation to terminate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, but I downloaded hadoop and set the value to HADOOP_HOME, after restarting the cluster, this error disappeared.